# Converting interval dates in factor class to date class?

Tags: r

I have a dataset gotten from this [website](http://www.cfr.org/interactives/GH_Vaccine_Map/#map). In this dataset there is a "Date" Column and its class is factor. I need to convert them to date class. So my questions are;

1. How should I convert it to date?
2. How can I handle with interval dates like `1/2011-12/2012`
3. There are only month and year values? So this is causing some problems, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but here's one approach:

```
df <- read.csv("map.csv")
dates <- t(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(df$Date),"-")))
df$dateFrom <- as.Date(paste0("01/",dates[,1]), format="%d/%m/%Y")
df$dateTo   <- as.Date(paste0("01/",dates[,2]), format="%d/%m/%Y")
head(df[,c("Date","dateFrom","dateTo")])
#             Date   dateFrom     dateTo
# 1 1/2010-12/2010 2010-01-01 2010-12-01
# 2 1/2011-12/2011 2011-01-01 2011-12-01
# 3 1/2012-11/2012 2012-01-01 2012-11-01
# 4        12/2012 2012-12-01 2012-12-01
# 5 1/2013-12/2013 2013-01-01 2013-12-01
# 6        12/2012 2012-12-01 2012-12-01
```

This parses your "Date" field into a "from" and "to" date and adds those as extra columns to `df`. Since `as.Date(...)` does indeed need a full date (month and year alone will  not suffice), I coerced the dates to the first of the month in all cases.

Comment: I am really appreciated for your help. When I type this code, almost everything fine. But, some date formats is like 0010-05-01 instead of 2010-05-01. Do you have any idea to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I downloaded the same file, `Added Source information for vaccine map.csv`, and ran this code. There are two rows where the "date" is a year only. These parse as `NA`. Everything else parses correctly. `range(df$dateFrom,na.rm=T)` produces: `"2008-01-01" "2014-02-01"` and `range(df$dateTo,na.rm=T)` produces `"2008-09-01" "2014-02-01"`.

Comment: I got same result now.Actually, I have another question. My goal in this project is plotting spreading of outbreaks by time(Date). Could you give me some suggestions please? How Can I create a plot like I said for each diseases? Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: By the way Can you check row 142 ( Mumps in Canada(whistler). dateFrom and dateTo are same which is 2011-04-01? So there must be a mistake here. But I could not understand.

Comment: Look at the original date for that row: it's 4/2011, so the from and to dates are the same.